# First-fit memory management and ordered lists

Tags: algorithm, list, memory-management, sequential

Im studying memory management and came across the following question.

> What happens to the first-fit method if it is applied to a list
>   ordered by block sizes?

From what I understand first-fit will simply claim the first lock that is big enough.  But what impact will an ordered list (by block size) have on the algorithm?

For more info take a look at the following: [Data structures and algorithms by Adam Drozdek](https://books.google.co.za/books?id=PRgLAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA667&lpg=PA667&dq=what%20happens%20to%20the%20first-fit%20method%20if%20it%20is%20applied%20to%20a%20list%20ordered%20by%20block%20sizes&source=bl&ots=zZHiKVmUyG&sig=2yeSCaDSclVYAhHdwUw8Ffk_Q5M&hl=en&sa=X&ei=DGiQVbXdBsKe7gbV3YGYBA&ved=0CCgQ6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=what%20happens%20to%20the%20first-fit%20method%20if%20it%20is%20applied%20to%20a%20list%20ordered%20by%20block%20sizes&f=false)

Comment: ordered how: increasing or decreasing?

Comment: @AmiTavory Unfortunately the original question doesn't specify. This is part of what confused me. If the list is sorted increasingly (ascending order) the first available block will be used. If the list is sorted decreasingly (descending order) the very first block will be used. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Agreed. I see it comes from a textbook, but it doesn't seem to be well defined. Increasing or decreasing? Irrespective, increasing/decreasing by how much? And starting at what size? Etc.

Comment: well isnt it simple? instead of searching the whole free space of memory block, you just binary search the amount of space you need and you find it in O(logN) time rather than O(N)